# Save Dynamic textbox to Database

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys I have this code below which will dynamically add textbox per click. my question is How can i save the dynamically created textbox into MYSQL Database

i want to save each textbox in each row. meaning one text box = one row

e.g

```
ID | NAME | Training (the textbox)|
1    john   Driving
2    john   swimming
3    john   running

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Add or Remove text boxes with jQuery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    #main {
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    -->
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="main">
        <h1>Add or Remove text boxes with jQuery</h1>
        <div class="my-form">
            <form role="form" method="post">
                  <label for="box1"><span class="namer">Name</span></label>
                   <input type="text" name="name" />
                <p class="text-box">
                    <label for="box1">Box <span class="box-number">1</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="boxes[]" value="" id="box1" />
                    <a class="add-box" href="#">Add More</a>
                </p>
                <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.my-form .add-box').click(function(){
            var n = $('.text-box').length + 1;
            if( 5 < n ) {
                alert('Stop it!');
                return false;
            }
            var box_html = $('<p class="text-box"><label for="box' + n + '">Box <span class="box-number">' + n + '</span></label> <input type="text" name="boxes[]" value="" id="box' + n + '" /> <a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></p>');
            box_html.hide();
            $('.my-form p.text-box:last').after(box_html);
            box_html.fadeIn('slow');
            return false;
        });
        $('.my-form').on('click', '.remove-box', function(){
            $(this).parent().css( 'background-color', '#FF6C6C' );
            $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function() {
                $(this).remove();
                $('.box-number').each(function(index){
                    $(this).text( index + 1 );
                });
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>



    // MY PHP Insert code

    <?php   
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con){
    die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("SLL",$con);

//please assume boxes = training

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $training= $_POST['boxes'];

    $AddQuery ="INSERT INTO db (name,training)VALUES ($name,training)"

   mysql_query($AddQuery, $con);
    ?>
```

Comment: Where's your PHP? You'll be needing this to insert

Comment: i know who to create a single insert command. but i dont know how to code multiple insert from dynamic textbox. please help

Comment: i've added my Insert code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly there (apart from the odd typo), `$_POST['boxes']` is an array, so just foreach loop [(explanation)](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) through each key in the array.

```
<?php   
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con){
    die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("SLL",$con);

    $name = $_POST['name'];

//please assume boxes = training
    foreach($_POST['boxes'] as $textbox){
        $training= $textbox;
        $AddQuery ="INSERT INTO db (name,training)VALUES ($name,$training)";
        mysql_query($AddQuery, $con);

    }
?>
```

**UPDATE**
To loop through with two or more input arrays, i.e. `name="boxes[]"` and `name="amount[]"`, it will need to be assumed that each `boxes[]` is relative to `amount[]`, i.e. `boxes[0]` goes with `amount[0]`, `boxes[1]` goes with `amount[1]`, `boxes[n]` goes with `amount[n]`. So, you will need a counter that increments every time the loop ends/restarts. See `$i`, you will see that the value of `$i` is being increased by 1 at the end of each go round the loop, and this is caught by the amount by key as `$_POST['amount'][$i]`.

The revised loop would be something like

```
$i = 0; 
foreach($_POST['boxes'] as $textbox){
    $training= $textbox;
    $amount = $_POST['amount'][$i];
    $AddQuery ="INSERT INTO db (name,training,amount)VALUES ($name,$training,$amount)";
    mysql_query($AddQuery, $con);
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: hello Thank you!!!!! it solve my problem!. im newbie and you help me bigtime. Thanks!

Comment: but how can i add 2 array inside foreach?? i mean like this foreach($_POST['boxes'] as $textbox AND $_POST['amount'] as $amount){//code here }

Comment: Updated my answer, lot of assumptions but you should get the gist.

Comment: wow GOD. thank you so so much!! it works! i dont know how to thank you. but thank you thank you!! appreciated your time!